# How to show selected cells of a table?

Tags: php, html, html-table, row, html-select

I have a table which show data from mysql database in HTML table like this:

[image: current table structure]

then I want to show like this with checkboxes:

[image: table structure look like]

after that user select some rows and submit then the selected rows shown in the next page so how could it be done in php with HTML.

Comment: just take 3 `<td>` instead of 2 in one row in your loop and then put check box into 3rd `<td>` ... this is all you do ..

Comment: i've already done this but how about selected row pass in next page?

Comment: firstly show what you attempt .. show us you code plz...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you started:

```
<table>
<?php
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $r['s_no']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['name']; ?></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="selected_s_no[]" value="<?php echo $r['s_no']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
</table>
```

On the submitted page there will be an array you can access with the selected `s_no` values

```
print_r($_REQUEST['selected_s_no'])
```

Comment: i want similar thing like this and i already know this and i want to know the way to pass complete table row with s.no, name and may be more and not only value?

Comment: Once you have the `s.no` numbers on the submit you can just query the database for that information.

Answer (score -1):

```
<table>
<?php
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $r['s_no']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['name']; ?></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="selected_s_no[]" value="<?php echo $r['s_no']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
</table>

on submitting page you can use foreach with selected values

foreach($_POST['selected_s_no'] as $value)
{
    //show data according to selected checkbox 
}
```

Comment: did you directly copy this from my answer?